# Discovering Repetitive Functions

Tags: number-theory, analysis, functions, exponential-function, math-history

I am curious to know if there is a way to have discovered the exponential function e, trigonometric functions and whatever other function out there which is equal to itself multiplied by some constant (or perhaps variable), k, before any of them were even discovered. In other words, is there a general way to find all the possible functions which has the property that it equals itself at least after some N number of derivatives if not for the first derivative. For example, e^x becomes e^x or e^3x becomes 3e^3x so d(f(x))/dx = kf(x)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Differential equations mate

Comment: Trig functions were discovered long before anyone ever took a derivative.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's right but is that a way to have discovered everything at once using a general method that encompasses all such functions and can give someone specific functions as they please?

Comment: The way to discover all functions satisfying $f^{(n)}(x)=kf(x)$ is to write down that equation, and then solve it. That's not too hard to do, once you have the ideas of higher derivatives and complex numbers. But maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes thank you that was what I needed. I wonder if someone has made a list of all such functions because that sounds pretty interesting to be honest.

Comment: I posted an answer a couple of days ago, giving all the functions. Does it meet your needs?

Comment: Are you still here, Captain?

Comment: Hey sorry I have been very busy. I don't absolutely need to know it but I was just curious in regards to this topic and I just wanted to be at ease knowing that this idea is already thought of. Thanks for the time and answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

All such functions are linear combinations of exponential functions. $f(x)=e^{{\root n\of k}x}$ satisfies $f^{(n)}(x)=kf(x)$. Let $\zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$ be a primitive complex $n$th root of unity, then $f_j(x)=e^{\zeta_n^j{\root n\of k}x}$ is a solution for $j=0,1,\dots,n-1$. The general solution is $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_jf_j(x)$. This includes such functions as $\cos x=(1/2)e^{ix}+(1/2)e^{-ix}$ which is the case $n=2$, $k=-1$.

Comment: This got out of my knowledge waaay too quickly. Isn't that the Reimann function that I see? Wow looks really complicated but at the same time the symbols are pretty beautiful

Comment: The Greek letter $\zeta$ ("zeta") is used for Riemann's function, but here it's something much simpler; it's a complex number you can  raise to an integer power to get $1$. Another way to write the formula for it is $\zeta_n=\cos(2\pi/n)+i\sin(2\pi/n)$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit, a square root of minus one. If complex numbers are not in your toolbox, then all solutions of "$n$th derivative of $f(x)$ is $kf(x)$" can be expressed in terms of exponential funtions $e^{ax}$ and trig functions $\sin bx$ and $\cos cx$ for appropriate $a,b,c$.

Comment: So are we OK now?

Comment: Come on, Captain, meet me halfway here.

Comment: Hey yes I am done with this question. Not sure if I should close it though

Comment: "close" is a technical term here on stackexchange, and I don't think you can close your question. You can probably delete it, though that would piss me off, after the work I put into it. You can "accept" my answer, by clicking in the check mark next to it – this way it won't keep popping up. And of course if you ever regain interest in the question you can come back to it and we can see whether I, or someone else, can do a better job of explaining the math.